# Shuffling an array of strings in vb.net

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I am developing a webpage in vb.net that will generate a number of multiple choice questions to the user. I need to shuffle the four answers which are already put in an array. Lets assume that I have to following array:

```
array = {"Correct", "Wrong1", "Wrong2", "Wrong3"}
```

I tried to use the following method:

```
Public Shared Function Shuffle(ByVal items() As String) As Array
        Dim max_index As Integer = items.Length - 1
        Dim rnd As New Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
        For i As Integer = 0 To max_index
            ' Pick an item for position i.
            Randomize()
            Dim j As Integer = rnd.Next(i, max_index)
            ' Swap them.
            Dim temp As String = items(i)
            items(i) = items(j)
            items(j) = temp
        Next i
        Return items
    End Function
```

The function is working really fine, but my problem is that if I have four questions, the answers will be shuffled for each question but the correct answer will be in one position like:

```
    array = {"Wrong1", "Correct", "Wrong2", "Wrong3"}
    array = {"Wrong2", "Correct", "Wrong3", "Wrong1"}
    array = {"Wrong3", "Correct", "Wrong1", "Wrong2"}
    array = {"Wrong1", "Correct", "Wrong3", "Wrong2"}
```

What I need is the correct answer to change its location from one question to another.
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several issues with your your Shuffle method and use of `Random`.

1. `Randomize` is for use with the old, legacy VB `Rnd` function.  It has no impact on the shiny new NET `Random` class.
2. There is rarely a need to provide a custom seed; in fact this can work against you.
3. Create one `Random` for the entire app to use rather than each time you shuffle (or click something).  And never create them in a loop - this almost guarantees repeated numbers.
4. The max argument to `Random.Next(min, max)` is *exclusive*, so your range is actually 1 element smaller than it should be.
5. Your Shuffle is pretty close, but has a few flaws:

   - Generally the NET version of the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is an in place shuffle (`Sub`) making it very efficient (rather than returning a new collection)
   - It is important to loops *backwards* thru the list or array.<sup>1</sup>

**The Standard Fisher-Yates Shuffle:**

```
' form/class level var
Private rnd As New Random()

Public Sub Shuffle(items As String())
    Dim j As Int32
    Dim temp As String

    For n As Int32 = items.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        j = rnd.Next(0, n + 1)
        ' Swap them.
        temp = items(n)
        items(n) = items(j)
        items(j) = temp
    Next n
End Sub
```

Output from 4 shuffles of the same starting array:

```
Shuffle #1    Wrong3   Correct  Wrong2   Wrong1   
Shuffle #2    Correct  Wrong2   Wrong1    Wrong3   
Shuffle #3    Wrong2   Correct  Wrong3    Wrong1   
Shuffle #4    Correct  Wrong1   Wrong2    Wrong3   
Shuffle #5    Correct  Wrong1   Wrong3    Wrong2
```

#### Variations

Rather than a global `Random` generator, you can pass it (useful as an extension method):

```
Public Sub Shuffle(items As String(), RNG As Random)
```

**Generic method for shuffling *many* types:**

```
' Generic shuffle for basic type arrays
Public Sub Shuffle(Of T)(items As T(), rng As Random)
    Dim temp As T
    Dim j As Int32

    For i As Int32 = items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        ' Pick an item for position i.
        j = rng.Next(i + 1)
        ' Swap 
        temp = items(i)
        items(i) = items(j)
        items(j) = temp
    Next i
End Sub
```

Examples:

```
Shuffle(intArray, myRnd)
Shuffle(strArray, myRnd)
Shuffle(colors, myRnd)
Shuffle(myButtons, myRnd)
```

**Simple Reordering**

Finally, for something simple where you might only reorder them once, a simple and usually-good-enough version using an extension method:

```
Dim ShuffledItems = myItems.OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next).ToArray()
```

This has less code and is easy to dash off, but is *much* less efficient.

<sup>1</sup> The reason that you want to loop backwards is to limit each array element to ***one*** swap.  Once "X" is moved to `items(j)` in the last step, that position is removed from consideration because `rnd.Next(0, n + 1)` will only pick *up to* the last element/loop index.  Many implementations get this wrong.

Comment: Great explanation, great examples and a great person! Thanks!