# Randomize letters in a word using different order each time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way on vb 2015 that I can take a word and randomize the order of the letters in a different order each time?

Comment: Please add some more details about what you need and how you have approached it already.

Comment: I am trying to take a word which I will input before the program starts and I wont to randomize the word so the letters are in different positions I haven't had a go at anything as I had no ideas.

Answer (score 2):

There are algorithms for generating all permutations of the letters. The Knuth algorithm is one of the simpler ones and is memory efficient. But if all you need is *any* permutation, then you can do a shuffle. A simple but effective shuffle would be to exchange the letter at each position with a letter from a random position. An old text book of mine referred to the below as the Monte Carlo shuffle.

```
Private Function ShuffleWord(Word As String) As String
    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim chars() As Char = Word.ToCharArray
    For i As Integer = 0 To chars.Length - 1
        j = rand.Next(Word.Length)
        Dim t As Char = chars(i)
        chars(i) = chars(j)
        chars(j) = t
    Next
    Return New String(chars)
End Function
```

You can call it this way:

```
TextBox1.Text = ShuffleWord(TextBox1.Text)
```

This approach is simple and intuitive, but there are other ways to do shuffles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Pencil-and-paper_method.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is flawed.  See [The Danger of Naïveté](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33619422/1070452).

Comment: @Plutonix You reference a nice article on shuffling, and I agree that the above algorithm is biased. One could argue that the unbiased algorithm is always the best--unless one is attempting to replicate a particular shuffling process. In any case, thanks for pointing this out, it will make us all better programmers.

Comment: Using a New Random is just wrong - it will produce the same result in a loop.  Also, the code doesnt comply with the wiki link you posted - namely the step of striking out an item once it is swapped so each item is swapped at most once.  The answer is to loop *backwards* using `rand.Next(0, i+1)`.  This locks/strikes out elements already swapped (`i` from the prev iterations is not in the `rand.Next()` range). When trying to replicate a pattern, Random is wholly unsuitable, Mersenne Twister is for just that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

The shortest would be [order by random number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359144/897326), like this:

```
Dim input As String = "Hello, World!"
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim shuffledInput As String = input.OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next).ToArray
'outputs something like: "!ld ,WoloeHlr"
```

A little explanation why it works - any string can be treated as an array of characters, which means you can apply LINQ on it, same as with any other IEnumerable(Of T). Second part is knowing that you can assign string from a char array, so below line works perfectly fine:

```
Dim charArray As String = {"a"c, "b"c, "c"c} 'contains "abc"
```

Another approach - string builder would be more efficient - but just to show the idea - create new string from `input` by randomly taking one character off:

```
Private Function randomizeString(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim rtn As String = ""
    Dim i As Integer

    While input.Length > 0
        i = ran.Next(0, input.Length)
        rtn &= input.Substring(i, 1)
        input = input.Remove(i, 1)
    End While

    Return rtn
End Function
```

Credit goes to [Satal Keto on this forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630975-Randomize-or-shuffle-a-String).

Comment: great answer, I didnt know you could order by rnd.next