# Guarantee a specific number is in a random number set

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

I have written code which randomly generates number and stores them in a hashset to prevent duplicates. However, each time i run the generator i need to generate a specific number as well as some other numbers and then store all the values including the number i wanted generated stored in a hashset in a random order.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Since you did not show any code, I assume you have a FOR LOOP. before that FOR LOOP, figure out which loop you will use your number and there you go.

Comment: You could generate N random numbers, then randomly replace some with the value(s) you want to be sure are used.  I am not sure how the hashset adds any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series of values with no repeats generally means a shuffle because a value *can* repeat in a series of random values.  I dont know what the range of values is, so I will guess.  This is easier than a hashset in a loop:

```
' use the same random object over and over
Private rng As New Random()
...
Dim MustHave As Int32 = 42

Dim values = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).
      OrderBy(Function(r) rng.Next()).
      Take(10).ToArray()

' it might already be in the set, so check
If values.Contains(MustHave) = False Then
    values(rng.Next(0, values.Length)) = MustHave
End If
```

Explanation of the first part:

- `Enumerable` is a Type with gobs of Shared methods to Sum, Average etc.  The code uses `Range` to create 100 values starting at 1.  This is to be the pool the value set comes from.
- Next, the contents are put in random order using the `Random` object created
- `Take` is another `IEnumerable` method to return `n` elements; here, 10.
- Finally, put them (the lucky 10) into an array

The last step checks that the value you want to appear, isn't already there before putting it in a random spot.

Using `OrderBy` to put them in a random order is often a simple-good-enough shuffle.  Alternatively, use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359144/1070452).  Its longer, but more efficient.

Comment: Any chance you could explain what the Function(r) bit does?

Comment: It is the function which provides the random value for the `OrderBy` clause or expression.  That entire construct is called `linq` which are implemented as extensions (hence all the dots (`.`)) and is very handy for doing all sorts of  selections and such on lists and arrays. `Function (r)` itself is called a lambda expression - basically an unnamed Function or Sub written inline