# Pick unique Random numbers

Tags: .net, vb.net, random

I'm trying to randomize a number in VB.NET 3 times. And each time I randomize a number it should be different from the other two numbers.

For example I have 3 integers. Int1,Int2 and Int3. I will randomize Int1 between 1-10 , and then I will randomize Int2 between 1-10 however the value shouldn't be equal to the value I randomized in Int1 and the same goes for Int3 it shouldn't equal to Int1 and Int2.

I have figured out how to randomize a number, this is the code I'm using:

```
Dim RndNumber As Random
Dim num,num2 As Integer
RndNumber = New Random
num = RndNumber.Next(1, 11)
num2 = RndNumber.Next(1, 11)
```

Now I'm stuck on how I make num2 randomize a number between 1-10 that is not equals to num.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In all the examples, `RNG` is a random number generator created from the NET `Random` class:

```
Private RNG = New Random()
```

#### Linq

If you only need two or three, you could loop until the current pick is not in the result set. But this is even simpler using some extension methods:

```
Dim nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).
                OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next).
                Take(3).
                ToArray()
```

This starts with all numbers between 1 and 10, puts them in random order, takes the first 3 and stores them in the `nums` array.  I used the multiline form, breaking after the `.`s to illustrate the steps.

Just change the range, size/count and `Take()` element as needed.  For instance, for something like a lottery with 5 unique numbers 1-69 (condensed form):

```
Dim winners = Enumerable.Range(1, 69).OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next()).Take(5).ToArray()
Dim powerball = Enumerable.Range(1, 26).OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next()).Take(1).First
```

Since the Powerball *can* be a repeat of the first numbers, it comes from its own pool. Since we only want one, we dont need an array, just the `First()`.

#### Manual

It is good to know the logic for these things, so this shows a manual version. This does it differently, by picking and actually checking random values:

```
' picked value storage
Dim picks As New List(Of Int32)

Dim pick As Int32          ' current candidate
Do
    pick = RNG.Next(1, 11)
    If picks.Contains(pick) = False Then
        picks.Add(pick)
    End If
Loop Until picks.Count = 3
```

Rather than loose vars, this uses a list to hold the picks.  This makes it easy to see if the current pick has already been selected.  For more than just a few values, use a `HashSet(Of Int32)` rather than a List for performance.

**Random Pairs**

To create a random *sets* of numbers with 2 of each, such as for a matching game, just double up the base pool of values then put them in random order:

```
' create pool of 2 values each for 1-13
Dim nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 13).ToArray()
' concat the set to make 2 of each value, randomize 
Dim pool = nums.Concat(nums).OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next).ToArray()
```

For a manual method you would have to check the count of each value in the loop.

#### 'Use up' Picks

One more variation is when you need a pool of randoms used periodically, but you don't know how many you will need in advance.  Examples would be the balls for a BINGO game or a deck of cards.

Rather than a global indexer pointing to the last slot used (or next slot to use), a `Stack(Of T)` (or a `Queue`) will "use up" values as you need them:

```
' create, randomize pool of 100 ints
Dim nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next).ToArray
' use array to create Stack<T>
Dim shoe As New Stack(Of Int32)(nums)

' same as:
Dim shoe = New Stack(Of Int32)(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).
                                OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next).ToArray())
```

This starts basically the same with 100 integers, randomized and stored in an array, but there is no `Take(n)` because we want them all.  They values are then stored in a stack collection.  Using it:

```
Console.WriteLine(shoe.Count)
For n As Int32 = 1 To 3
    Console.WriteLine("Picked #{0}", shoe.Pop)
Next
Console.WriteLine(shoe.Count)
```

When you `Pop` a value it is removed from the collection automatically.  If you use a lot of values from the shoe, you will want to check the count to make sure it is not empty.

> 100
>   Picked #12
>   Picked #69
>   Picked #53
>   97

After drawing 3 values, the shoe has only 97 values remaining.

**Random Notes**

In all cases your `Random` generator should be a form level object  which you create **once**.  Never create them in a loop or you will likely get the same value over and over.

The `OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next)` method of randomizing is usually good enough for casual use, but it is inefficient.  If you will be randomizing large sets and/or using it frequently you should consider using a proper shuffle such as [the Fisher-Yates shuffle shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359144/1070452).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, your answer sorted my problem out.