# Showing Multiple Numbers from RNG

Tags: vb.net

What I am trying to do is create an RNG button that will generate 5 unique numbers between 1-99. This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub GenerateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GenerateButton.Click
    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim rememberset As New HashSet(Of Integer)
    Dim value As Integer

    While rememberset.Count < 6
        value = rand.Next(1, 99)
        If rememberset.Add(value) Then
            LotteryLabel.Text = value.ToString()
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Every time I click the generate button, I just get 1 number. I'm trying to get 5 to display in this format (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You only have one label, so it's not clear how you wanted to show the five other values.  Use a ListBox?

Comment: your label is just showing the last pick - not the previous ones

Comment: you also do not need a hashset to get 5 unique values:  `Dim picks = Enumerable.Range(1,99).OrderBy(Function (r) rand.Next()).Take(5).ToArray()` will do it all.  Your Random object should be class/form level not recreated for each button click

Comment: To display them:  `Label.Text = String.Join(", ", picks)`

Comment: Definitely taking notes on that one. A lot cleaner than what I had. Thanks!

Comment: Seems applicable to what you are creating: [Pick unique Random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35120518/1070452)   upvote it if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LotteryLabel.Text is always set to the string of only one number ( I guess you will see only the last number)

You need to append the value: Easy (but maybe slow) solution should be

`LotteryLabel.Text = LotteryLabel.Text & ", " & value.ToString()`