# VB - comparing numbers in two labels

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm doing a school project in Visual Basic (using visual studio 2015) and i'm kinda stuck.

My goal is to create a lottery, where player chooses 6 numbers from checkboxes, then he generates six random numbers (1 - 49) and finally, those two sets should be compared and needed result is the number of correctly guessed numbers.

I have both results (guessed numbers, generated numbers) saved in two different labels.

The checkboxes itself are genereted like this:

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



    lev = 20
    tt = 0
    For j = 1 To 50
        tt = tt + 1
        n = n + 1
        box(j) = New CheckBox
        box(j).Name = "box(" & Str(j) & ")"
        If n = 11 Then lev = lev + 110 : n = 1 : tt = 1
        box(j).Left = lev
        box(j).Parent = Me
        box(j).Top = tt * 20
        box(j).Tag = j
        box(j).Text = j
        box(j).Visible = True
    Next
    box(50).Enabled = False
End Sub
```

First label (guessed numbers) is filled this way (i'm not posting whole code)

```
For j = 1 To 50
            If box(j).Checked = True Then Label9.Text = Label9.Text + " " + box(j).Text
Next
```

and the second one (generated numbers) like this:

```
Do
        rn = rg.Next(1, 50)
        If Not r.Contains(rn) Then
            r.Add(rn)
        End If
    Loop Until r.Count = 6

    Label1.Text = r(0).ToString + " " + r(1).ToString + " " + r(2).ToString + " " + r(3).ToString + " " + r(4).ToString + " " + r(5).ToString
```

any idea how to compare numbers stored in those labels and get the result (number of correctly guessed numbers).

thanks in advance

Comment: When you put *numbers* into lables they become text which is something quite different.  Putting all of each group into *one* label makes one long string of text and hard to compare.  Use variables like an array or list (ie dont glue them together if you know you need them separately to compare)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try. So if i store values into array, how do i compare them to get the number of correctly guessed numbers?

Comment: How would you compare a real lottery ticket to a set of winning numbers?  One at a time - a loop.

Comment: There are other, shorter ways to pick the lotto numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35120518/1070452

Answer (score 0):

You can compare numbers in the labels by splitting the Text properties of the labels into arrays of strings and converting them to integer arrays. First though there is a tiny problem with your code that adds the guessed numbers to the label.

```
For j = 1 To 50
            If box(j).Checked = True Then Label9.Text = Label9.Text + " " + box(j).Text
Next
```

The " " should be moved to the end of the line because at the moment, the label will always start with a space and that messes with the function below. So you should have -

```
For j = 1 To 50
            If box(j).Checked = True Then Label9.Text = Label9.Text + box(j).Text + " "
Next
```

Ok. The function below splits the two text labels into their own array and loops through the guesses and checks if any number is contained in the generated numbers. It then returns the number of matches.

```
Private Function ComparePicks() As Integer
    Dim numbersMatched As Integer
    Dim picks(5) As Integer
    Dim generatedNumbers(5) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        picks(i) = CInt(Split(Label9.Text, " "c)(i))
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        generatedNumbers(i) = CInt(Split(Label1.Text, " "c)(i))
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        If generatedNumbers.Contains(picks(i)) Then
            numbersMatched += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return numbersMatched
End Function
```