# Using control array for shuffling picture boxes

Tags: arrays, vb.net

So I want to create a concentration-style memory matching game. But for now I want to just focus on filling picture boxes. I want the pictures to be shuffled in a random order each time the game is loaded. My teacher recommended using a control array and sent me this link http://www.acthompson.net/DotNet/ControlArrays.htm

I'm still quite confused as there's red lines everywhere and  I don't know how to add the images to the program. Initially I wanted to add the pictureboxes whilst building but this tutorial suggests doing it at runtime.

There's red lines under  InitializeComponent()and the card()'s. Why? And how do I add images that I have saved in a file?

Also I'd like to know if I need the double Class declaration? The name of the class is 'Form' and 'Form1' is referring to the form itself. When I just declare 'Form1' it says 'class Form1 and partial class Form1 clash.' Can I just declare 'Form' and it will be able to interact with the form?

tldr; how to fill a control array with picture boxes which can be shuffled each time the game is run?

Thank you in advance. My code so far:

```
Public Class Form

    Public Class Form1

        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

        Dim cards(23) As PictureBox


   Public Class Form
Public Class Form1

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Dim cards(23) As PictureBox

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        cards = New PictureBox() {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4, PictureBox5, PictureBox6, PictureBox7, PictureBox8, PictureBox9, PictureBox10, PictureBox11, PictureBox12, PictureBox13, PictureBox14, PictureBox15, PictureBox16, PictureBox17, PictureBox18, PictureBox19, PictureBox20, PictureBox21, PictureBox22, PictureBox23, PictureBox24}
    End Sub

End Class
```

End Class

I've tried this and various other configurations but ti still isn't working. Where have I made a mistake?

UPDATE:

So I've played around with this and I've had a couple of issues.
1. It says that Path is not declared so I did IO.Path and that seems to be okay. I don't know if it's suitable though
2. It says that  PictureBox1,etc, are not declared and inaccessible. The same for Img Folder. I suppose the path to the folder with my images is incorrect

Public Class Form1

```
'picture boxes

Private pBoxes As PictureBox()

'images

Private imgs As String()

'random number generator

Private rNum As Random

'cover image

Private coverImg As String = "bg.jpeg"

'timer

Private dt As DateTime

'turns cards

Private pbFirst As PictureBox

Private pbSecond As PictureBox

Private matches As Int32 = 0



Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim ImgFolder As String

    rNum = New Random()

    pBoxes = New PictureBox() {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4, PictureBox5, PictureBox6, PictureBox7, PictureBox8, PictureBox9, PictureBox10, PictureBox11, PictureBox12, PictureBox13, PictureBox14, PictureBox15, PictureBox16, PictureBox17, PictureBox18, PictureBox19, PictureBox20, PictureBox21, PictureBox22, PictureBox23, PictureBox24}

    'where images are stored

    ImgFolder = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath("H:\Test images"))

    coverImg = IO.Path.Combine(ImgFolder, coverImg)


    For Each p As PictureBox In pBoxes

        p.ImageLocation = coverImg

    Next

    'NewGame()

End Sub

'Private Sub NewGame()

' reset everything that matters

'matches = 0

'pbFirst = Nothing

'pbSecond = Nothing

' repick, reshuffle

'PickImages()

'Shuffle()

'dt = DateTime.Now

'tmrMain.Enabled = True

'End Sub
```

End Class

Yet another update:

I did have pictureboxes on my first version but not in this one. Can't believe I made such a silly mistake... It's fixed that but it is still saying my ImgFolder is undeclared and inaccessible. Btw, thank you so much for your patience and help so far.

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

```
'array of picture boxes
Private pBoxes As PictureBox()
'array of images
Private imgs As String()
'random number generator
Private rNum As Random
'cover image
Private coverImg As String = "bg.jpeg"

'timer
Private dt As DateTime

'turns cards
Private pbFirst As PictureBox
Private pbSecond As PictureBox
Private matches As Int32 = 0


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    rNum = New Random()

    pBoxes = New PictureBox() {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4,
                           PictureBox5, PictureBox6, PictureBox7, PictureBox8,
                           PictureBox9, PictureBox10, PictureBox11, PictureBox12, PictureBox13, PictureBox14, PictureBox15, PictureBox16, PictureBox17, PictureBox18, PictureBox19, PictureBox20, PictureBox21, PictureBox22, PictureBox23, PictureBox24}

    ' where you keep YOUR images 

    ImgFolder = "F:\COMPUTER SCIENCE\Test images"

    coverImg = Path.Combine(ImgFolder, coverImg)
    For Each p As PictureBox In pBoxes
        p.ImageLocation = coverImg
    Next

    'NewGame()
End Sub

'Private Sub NewGame()
' reset everything that matters
'matches = 0
'pbFirst = Nothing
'pbSecond = Nothing
' repick, reshuffle
'PickImages()
'Shuffle()

'dt = DateTime.Now
'tmrMain.Enabled = True
'End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Instead of shuffling UI COntrols which will require resetting the location, just shuffle the images that are mapped to them. `InitializeComponent()` belongs in `Sub New` and you cannot reference any controls until they are created which is after `Sub New` runs

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Like this?:Public Sub New Board()
            InitializeComponent()

            cards(0) = PictureBox1
            cards(1) = PictureBox2
            cards(2) = PictureBox3
            cards(3) = PictureBox4
            cards(4) = PictureBox5
            cards(5) = PictureBox6
            cards(6) = PictureBox7
        etc
        End Sub

Comment: @AlphaOne Please try what Plutonix suggested and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Leave `Sub New` alone = The VB IDE will create that for you. then `Cards = New PictureBox() {PictureBox1, PictureBox2...}`  The only think you need that for is mapping - they can stay in the same spot, just change which images are shown in them

Comment: Do you have picturebox controls on your form named `Picturebox1` etc - the original post indicated you did.  For `IO.Path`, if you hover over such errors the IDE will offer to fix it - if you add `Imports System.IO` to the top (which is what the IDE will do) you dont have to use the long reference.

Comment: `ImgFolder ="H:\Test images"` is also all you need - you are not combining anything or getting the folder name from MyDocuments as in the answer

Comment: This is not a forum so if you want to be sure someone sees an edit, you should ping them in comments using @+username (the same is true when more than one person comments).  I just happened to notice these latest edits... Somehow a line got missed in the answer.  Add `Private ImgFolder As String` up with the form level declarations - you'll need/want the folder name when you load the other images.

Comment: @Plutonix ok thank you that seems to have removed the error message! Only thing is now when I run the code the pictureboxes don't display the images or cover img, they are shown as white boxes with a red cross. Any possible reason why?

Comment: You would have to have an image file named "bg.jpeg" in the `"F:\COMPUTER SCIENCE\Test images"` folder.  Thats what you are telling the code to use.  The red cross means it cant find it  (all the answer does so far is to show that image - AFAIK the others have no been loaded yet)

Comment: @Plutonix oh of course. I just had it in the computer science folder. I want to try and figure out adding the images to be matched by myself now, but could you give me a little hint? Should I do it in a similar format to how I added the cover img or do I do that in the shuffle routine which is commented out?

Comment: I have no idea how yours are named.  I used that deck of cards so I could pick 6 out of 52 to make the game different each time.  The bullet points in the answer explains the steps.  The first one is to load the images.  You'd show them in the click event, but there are several intermediate steps before that (like loading them).  Since this answers the question posed as well as several others not asked, please click the checkmark to close this question.  If you get stuck on subsequent steps just ask another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want to load the match images into the `PictureBox`es at startup - they should start with the same image until they are picked, no?  You will also want to avoid actually using images at all - if you create/load images, you are also responsible for disposing of them.  Use the `ImageLoacation`property to specify the path to a file.

This game version uses images from a deck of cards.  This is just the start up since this appears to be homework.

```
Public Class frmGame
    Private pbs As PictureBox()
    Private myImgs As String()        ' img file paths
    Private RNG As Random

    Private ImgFolder As String
    Private CoverImg As String = "b1fv.png"
    ' crude timer
    Private dt As DateTime    

    ' turn elements - first and second pbs clicked,
    ' matches so you know when it is Game Over
    Private pbFirst As PictureBox
    Private pbSecond As PictureBox
    Private matches As Int32 = 0

    Private Sub frmGame_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RNG = New Random()

        pbs = New PictureBox() {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4,
                               PictureBox5, PictureBox6, PictureBox7, PictureBox8,
                               PictureBox9, PictureBox10, PictureBox11, PictureBox12}

        ' where you keep YOUR images
        ImgFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
                                 "DevGraphics", "Cards")

        CoverImg = Path.Combine(ImgFolder, CoverImg)
        For Each p As PictureBox In pbs
            p.ImageLocation = CoverImg
        Next

        NewGame()
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewGame()
        ' reset verything that matters
        matches = 0
        pbFirst = Nothing
        pbSecond = Nothing
        ' repick, reshuffle
        PickImages()
        Shuffle()

        dt = DateTime.Now
        tmrMain.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

- The cards are from www.jfitz.com/cards/ which apparently no longer exists
- In the click event, the code can store the first and second PB clicked using `pbFirst` and `pbSecond`
- `PickImages` would load the file names to the array

  - start with an array of values 1-52
  - shuffle them (your shuffle on your previous question is wrong - there are many [Shuffle answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120518/1070452) on SO)
  - take half as many as you need (12 for a 24 match game), duplicate them
- Shuffle that array

  - map them by showing `myImgs(n)` in a `PictureBox` where n is the index of the clicked picturebox in the array above
  - the fitz cards have a numerical set where `1.png` is the Ace-Spades, 2 maps to the 2-spades etc so converting an integer to a card image file name is simple.
- `CoverImg` is the generic you-havent-found-a-match image.  You could leave them blank

Using `ImageLocation` rather than an image also allows you to easily compare if `pbFirst` has the same image as `pbSecond`

Add timers for game and delays, and eventually a 12 card version might look like:

[image]

You appear to have a form declaration within a form.  I'd start over with a new form.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see this before editing my original post. I'll have a play around with this.

Comment: You'll have to comment out the calls to methods that you havent written yet  (PickImages(), Shuffle()) but you should be able to get the form to load with either the common default image or none at all.  If so, please click the checkmark so this gets moved off the Unanswered list.  You should also take the [Tour]