# How to turn over cards in card game?

Tags: vb.net

I have created a card game where 2 x 12 different images will be loaded into 24 picture boxes in vb forms. My intention is for the user to turn over two cards at a time, trying to find pairs to match. Each time the game is loaded, there will be different pictures and they will be in different positions. So far I have loaded the image for the back of the card in the game successfully but I can’t turn them over to see if my images have loaded successfully. 
I am not concerned about shuffling them yet, I just want to see if the images have loaded and to be able to have two cards turned over at a time. I’m really confused as I’m not used to using VB for such tasks so any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Board

    ' as per stackoverflow Terms of Service
    ' this code comes from
    ' http://stackoverflow.com/a/40707688

    'array of picture boxes
    Private pBoxes As PictureBox()
    'array of images
    Private imgs As String() = {"1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "12.jpg", "13.jpg", "14.jpg", "15,jpg", "16.jpg", "17.jpg", "18.jpg", "19.jpg", "20.jpg", "21.jpg", "22.jpg", "23.jpg", "24.jpg"}
    'random number generator
    Private RNG = New Random
    'cover image
    Private coverImg As String = "bg.jpg"

    'timer
    Private dt As DateTime

    'turns cards
    Private pbFirst As PictureBox
    Private pbSecond As PictureBox
    Private matches As Int32 = 0

    'Folder where images are held
    Private ImgFolder As String


    Private Sub Board1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        RNG = New Random()

        'array of picture boxes
        pBoxes = New PictureBox() {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4,
        PictureBox5, PictureBox6, PictureBox7, PictureBox8,
        PictureBox9, PictureBox10, PictureBox11, PictureBox12, PictureBox13, PictureBox14, PictureBox15, PictureBox16, PictureBox17, PictureBox18, PictureBox19, PictureBox20, PictureBox21, PictureBox22, PictureBox23, PictureBox24}

        'where images are located
        ImgFolder = "F:  \COMPUTER SCIENCE\Test images"

        coverImg = Path.Combine(ImgFolder, coverImg)
        For Each p As PictureBox In pBoxes
            p.ImageLocation = coverImg
        Next

        NewGame()
    End Sub
    'Take images from file
    Private Sub PickImages()

        Dim nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToArray()

        Dim pool = nums.Concat(nums).OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next).ToArray()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Shuffle()

    End Sub
    ' reset everything 
    Private Sub NewGame()

        matches = 0
        pbFirst = Nothing
        pbSecond = Nothing
        ' repick, reshuffle
        PickImages()
        Shuffle()

        dt = DateTime.Now
        'tmrMain.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you are following the advice on the unaccreditted post all your code comes from, you dont want to load images, just load the filenames into a 12 element string array.   Then it is simply `pbFirst.ImageLocation = myImgs(index)`. As is, your string array is just the file name without the path. If it is a match game, you dont need a pool of 24 images, just 12; however you might want those 12 to come from a larger pool so that the same 12 images are not used over and over.  Filenames rather than Images makes this and other things simpler.  Filling the array for each game *is* the hardest part..

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the points to comments however are you clicking on the pictures to turn them over? If so I think you would just need to have an event such as the below to load the back of the card image.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = ("Path to Picture of back of the card")
    PictureBox1.Load()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and over-think this - forget about "turning them over" simply change the image:

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox2.Click 'etc
    dim index as short
    ' to do: get the index of the PictureCard
    If sender.Image is coverImg then
        sender.Image = imgs(index) ' in stead of 0, use the index of the picture card
    Else
        sender.Image = coverImage
    End if
End Sub
```