# Random number check array for unique

Tags: arrays, vb.net

This is for a school project, and the task is to create a random number generator, that produces 6 results (numbers), these numbers has to be stored into an array, following this once the numbers have been chosen a button then to sort them in ascending order using bubble sort.

The issue i am having is that, i am getting the duplicated numbers in my array, but i have managed to complete the rest of the requirements.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim pickedNumbers(5) As Integer

Private Function getRandomNumber()
    Randomize()
    Dim randomNumber As Integer = CInt(Int((59 * Rnd()) + 1))
    If pickedNumbers.Contains(randomNumber) Then
        getRandomNumber()
    End If
    Return randomNumber
End Function

Private Sub addNumbers()
    For i = 0 To 5
        pickedNumbers(i) = getRandomNumber()
    Next
    outputNumbers()
End Sub

Private Sub sortNumbers()
    Dim Temp As Integer
    For i = 5 To 1 Step -1
        For k = 0 To i - 1
            If pickedNumbers(k) > pickedNumbers(k + 1) Then
                Temp = pickedNumbers(k)
                pickedNumbers(k) = pickedNumbers(k + 1)
                pickedNumbers(k + 1) = Temp
            End If
        Next
    Next
    outputNumbers()
End Sub

Private Sub outputNumbers()
    tb1.Text = pickedNumbers(0)
    tb2.Text = pickedNumbers(1)
    tb3.Text = pickedNumbers(2)
    tb4.Text = pickedNumbers(3)
    tb5.Text = pickedNumbers(4)
    tb6.Text = pickedNumbers(5)
End Sub

Private Sub btnPickNumbers_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPickNumbers.Click
    addNumbers()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSortOrder_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSortOrder.Click
    sortNumbers()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            ctrl.Text = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

I am trying to recall my function, if the number exists to generated another.

Comment: I tried typing in visual basic in the tags box, and VBA came up, my apologies.

Comment: Random numbers are not necessarily unique. If the second number isn't allowed to be the same as the first number, it isn't random.

Comment: Can't you just check if the new generated number already exists in the array, and if so generate another one? Preferrably you'd do this in the loop of `addNumbers()`. However it'd require for instance a `While` loop (inside your existing loop) so that you keep generating new numbers until you find a unique one.

Comment: That is what i was aiming for @VisualVincent to check if the number already exists in the array, if it does then do another. I thought that this `If pickedNumbers.Contains(randomNumber) Then` would check it.

Comment: Try Googling "shuffle". Use `Enumerable.Range` to create a `List(Of Integer)` that contains the numbers from 1 to N, then use the shuffle code to randomise the list.

Comment: [Pick unique Random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35120454/1070452)

Answer (score 0):

You should only call Randomize() once in your program.

When you call Randomize(), you are seeding a random number sequence. It's not really random. It's a pseudo-random deterministic sequence. For any given seed, the sequence will always be the same.

When Randomize() is called without an argument, it uses the Timer() function to seed the sequence. The Timer() function has a resolution of just one second. If you call Randomize() without an argument more than once per second, each call resets the sequence back to the first pseudo-random number.

You are calling Randomize() every time your getRandomNumber() function is called, and that is happening in a tight loop that undoubtedly takes less than a second to execute.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment, perhaps if i put the Randomize() in my form load then it would only call once?

Comment: Yes, or define a constructor for your Form1 class.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out my answer, based on the suggestions @VisualVincent provided.

```
    Private Function getRandomNumber()
        Return CInt(Int((59 * Rnd()) + 1))
    End Function

    Private Sub addNumbers()
        Dim randomNumber As Integer
        For i = 0 To 5
            randomNumber = getRandomNumber()
            While Not pickedNumbers.Contains(randomNumber)
                pickedNumbers(i) = randomNumber
            End While
        Next
        outputNumbers()
    End Sub
```

Thank you!