# Read a random excel cell that has not been read before

Tags: excel, vb.net

My program gives the user a quiz based on an excel file. The questions appear in a random order. There are 5 possible questions in each row of the excel file (n, 3-7) and the answer is always in the second cell of that row (n, 2). There are 135 rows but the first two rows are unrelated to the questions. The user gets a point for answering the question correctly, and they should try to answer as many questions as they can within the time limit, so when the time is up the user will never get to see the unasked questions. The problem I need help with is that there is a rare chance (1 in 665) that a question could be repeated. How can I prevent this? (Also, i'm very new to programming)

Code for question generation

```
Private Sub newquestion()
    'New Question
    Randomize()
    row = CInt(rnd.Next(3, 135))
    key = CInt(rnd.Next(3, 7))
    lblgametype.Text = "Guess the answer from the hint"
    lblquestion.Text = worksheet.Cells(row, key).Value
End Sub
```

Code for checking the answer

```
Private Sub OnKeyDownHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtanswer.KeyDown
    'Prevent that annoying ass windows ding sound
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then                
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True                  
    End If                                         

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then 'If the user presses Enter while txtanswer is selected...
        userguess = txtanswer.Text 'Assign the text the user enters to the global userguess variable

        If userguess.ToUpper = worksheet.Cells(row, 2).Value.ToString.ToUpper Then
            'User answers a question correct
            lblcorrect.ForeColor = Color.Green       
            lblcorrect.Text = "Correct. +1"          
            txtanswer.Text = ""                      
            userguess = ""                           
            abilityscore += 1                        
            lblscore.Text = "Score: " & abilityscore 
            If abilityscore > abilityhighscore Then  
                abilityhighscore = abilityscore      
            End If                                   

            newquestion()

        Else
            'User answers a question incorrectly
            lblcorrect.ForeColor = Color.Red       
            lblcorrect.Text = "incorrect."         
            txtanswer.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then 'If the user presses escape while txtanswer is selected...
        btnskip.PerformClick() 'Treat it as if they pressed skip
    End If
End Sub
```

Code for question skip

```
Private Sub btnskip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnskip.Click
    Me.TargetDT = Me.TargetDT.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)) 'Subtract 15 seconds from the timer
    txtanswer.Focus() 'Reset focus back to the textbox

    newquestion()
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that random does not mean unique.  You need a shuffle: see [Pick unique Random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35120454/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix I read over your answer to that guy's question and I believe the answer I'm looking for is in the "Random Pairs" section of that answer. I've never used lists or arrays before. Could you show me what that would look like for my code? Also, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you quiz was 5 questions: `rowNums = Enumerable.Range(3, 135).OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next()).Take(5).ToArray()`  that will hold all 5 xl row numbers for this game.  the pair thing would be for like a concentration type game.  `RNG` would be a NET `Random` object not that legacy VB `Rnd` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

132 rows each with 5 candidate questions is a sort of odd way of storing them.  I'm guessing that it is basically 5 ways of putting the same question or they at least have the same correct answer.

I cant be sure, but it seems that being sure to pick a different row each time would be enough.

```
Public Class frmQuizzer

    ' form level variables
    Private RNG As New Random()
    Private rowNums As Int32()
    Private rowIndex As Int32
```

I will guess that a game or round will be 10 questions.  So, in a `NewGame` method (so you can run it again without restarting the app):

```
' which row to use this turn
rowIndex = 0
rowNums = Enumerable.Range(3, 135).
            OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next()).
            Take(10).
            ToArray()
```

Thats your 10 different XL rows to use.  You can pick the cell using the RNG object too:

```
key = RNG.Next(3,8)         ' the MAX is exclusive!
row = rowNums(rowIndex)
' "move" to next question
rowIndex += 1
lblquestion.Text = worksheet.Cells(row, key).Value
```

Personally, rather than tracking a `rowIndex` which can get messed up, I might use a `Stack` which will act like a deck shoe to "use" up" row numbers:

```
Private rowNums As Stack(Of Int32)
```

Fill it from the array created:

```
Dim nums = Enumerable.Range(3, 135).
            OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next).
            Take(10).
            ToArray()
rowNums = New Stack(Of Int32)(nums)
```

Get one and use it:

```
' Pop gets the next value and removes it from the list
lblquestion.Text = worksheet.Cells(rowNums.Pop(), key).Value
```

No indexer to track and no chance of it getting out of synch.

More

- **[Pick unique Random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120518/1070452)**
- For less casual things, rather than reordering/randomizing the array, use **[an actual shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359144/1070452)**