# making a bingo game and everyone has the same number

Tags: vb.net, list, random

I'm making a programme that creates a bingo card for 100 people and gives them all different numbers. but just now the code that i have is giving everyone the exact same 15 numbers. any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
  Structure Number
        Dim number As Integer
    End Structure
    Structure Player
        Dim name As String
        Dim numbers() As Number
        Dim numbers_left As Integer
    End Structure
    Dim players As New List(Of Player)
    Dim selectednumber As Integer
    Dim used As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim random As New Random
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Number As Number
        Dim player As Player
        ReDim player.numbers(14)

        For i = 1 To 100
            For j = 0 To 14
SelectNumber:   Number.number = random.Next(1, 101)
                If player.numbers IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each item In player.numbers
                        If item.number = Number.number Then
                            GoTo SelectNumber
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                player.numbers(j).number = Number.number
            Next
            player.name = ("Bill" & i)
            player.numbers_left = 15
            players.Add(player)
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: so, the random method always create same number?

Comment: can you make random variable static?

Comment: @AryanFirouzyan. i'm not sure but i have is so i can see what each player has. and every player has the same numbers as each other. so player1.numbers(0) is the same as player2.numbers(0) if that makes any sense

Comment: can you debug to see if random values are the same. Random function seed time to generate new value and this is probably your case

Comment: Im not familiar with vb syntax. is it posible to make **Static Dim random As New Random**?

Comment: it says 'static' is not valid on a member variable declaration

Comment: Are you obliged to use structures here? If not then I would suggest that you first get rid of that `Number` structure altogether as it offers nothing. I would also suggest declaring `Player` as a class rather than a structure.  I would then restructure your code somewhat.  For one thing, there is **NEVER** a need to use `GoTo`.

Comment: what about **Static random As New Random**

Comment: `Static` is wrong.  It would be `Shared` if anything but there's no need for that anyway.  That's not the issue.

Comment: The Structure should be a class and always use one random per app unless/until you know what you are doing,  See also  [Pick unique Random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35120454/1070452) for more/better pick methods as well as some random info

Comment: BTW you pick 100 Bingo values but US Bingo uses 75 numbers and UK 90.  If you use Enumerable on the link above you can get all the numbers at once **and** randomize them and get rid of that awful GoTo

Comment: I’ll gladly sacrifice my ill earned accepted answer for the cleaner solution @Plutonix mentions.  This code is confounding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll admit I'm not completely following all the logic, but it looks like you need to re-initialize the player at each loop, since I think you're always testing against the first player.

```
Structure Number
        Dim number As Integer
    End Structure
    Structure Player
        Dim name As String
        Dim numbers() As Number
        Dim numbers_left As Integer
    End Structure
    Dim players As New List(Of Player)
    Dim selectednumber As Integer
    Dim used As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim random As New Random
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For i = 1 To 100
            Dim Number As Number
            Dim player As Player
            ReDim player.numbers(14)
            For j = 0 To 14
SelectNumber:   Number.number = random.Next(1, 101)
                If Player.numbers IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each item In Player.numbers
                        If item.number = Number.number Then
                            GoTo SelectNumber
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                Player.numbers(j).number = Number.number
            Next
            Player.name = ("Bill" & i)
            Player.numbers_left = 15
            players.Add(Player)
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: sorry. that you couldn't follow all the logic. i kinda do my own think and only i mostly understand it. sorry again

Comment: Thanks, if this worked, can you accept this as the answer?  I’m a little tentative on this answer since I’m not following what originally was happening, but I guess if it works for you...