# VB .Net Shuffle 2 dimensional array of Strings - more elegantly

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array, shuffle

Sometimes you just know you're going to get shot down over a question, but here goes nothing.

I have a 2 dimensional array of Strings named Questions, yes it's quiz. And WITHOUT changing the original "Questions" array type to something easier like a Structure List, is there a more elegant way to shuffle the order of Questions?

This is what I have:

```
'1st I create 3 arrays to hold the 3 components of each Question
Dim arrQ((Questions.Length / 4) - 1) As String  'question
Dim arrA((Questions.Length / 4) - 1) As String  'answer
Dim arrM((Questions.Length / 4) - 1) As String  'media name

'2nd I copy the values from question array into individual arrays
Dim z As Integer
For z = 0 To (Questions.Length / 4) - 1
    arrQ(z) = Questions(0, z)
    arrA(z) = Questions(1, z)
    arrM(z) = Questions(2, z)
Next

'create an array to hold our shuffled questions
Dim x As Integer
Dim randarray(total_quizquestions - 1) As Integer

'create a list that we can remove index once they've been added to randarray
Dim list As New ArrayList
For i As Integer = 0 To total_quizquestions - 1
    list.Add(i)
Next i

'add and remove
Dim rand As New Random
Dim index As Integer
For x = 0 To total_quizquestions - 1
    index = rand.Next(0, list.Count)
    randarray(x) = list(index)
    list.RemoveAt(index)
Next

'clear original Questions
ReDim Preserve Questions(3, total_quizquestions - 1)

'add back to questions using randarray random number to get rows from arrQ etc.
Dim f As Integer = 0
For f = 0 To total_quizquestions - 1
    Questions(0, f) = arrQ(randarray(f))
    Questions(1, f) = arrA(randarray(f))
    Questions(2, f) = arrM(randarray(f))
Next f
```

Hey presto, my code works but it's so ugly I'm ashamed! Oh and yes Questions does have 4 elements but I'm only interested in the first 3.
Be kind...

Comment: `is there a more elegant way to shuffle the order of Questions?`, short answer is **yes**, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise

Comment: If you used a single object to group the question, answer, and media name, you could have a single array to shuffle with no need to keep multiple array orders in sync...

Comment: At this point, you could just have an other array of random index to the questions. That way your question array stays orderly and you just loop the random index array. You also say "Structure List" in your question, you should use "Object\Class List" instead.

Comment: #ps2goat is right. I was going to suggest a `struct` or `class` to store each { Q, A, Media}. If you use a class, you could add your randomized index in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ does not play nicely with 2D arrays, so your requirement of not changing the structure of the base array rules out a lot of nice, elegant solutions.

That being said, you can use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359144/87698) to randomize your array in-place.

This code is based on the answer I linked to in the previous paragraph (credit goes to Nat Pongjardenlarp). I have adapted it to your 2D array. Since you did not provide a MCVE, it's completely untested.

```
Dim rnd As New Random()

For n = total_quizquestions - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim j = rnd.Next(0, n + 1)

    ' Swap all three components of the question
    For component = 0 To 2
        Dim temp = Questions(component, n)
        Questions(component, n) = Questions(component, j)
        Questions(component, j) = temp
    Next component
Next n
```

---

And, just for fun (and posterity), here is a generalized (and tested) version without "magic numbers" that shuffles *any* 2D array:

```
Private rnd As New Random()

Sub Shuffle2DArray(Of T)(arr As T(,))
    For row = arr.GetUpperBound(1) To arr.GetLowerBound(1) Step -1
        Dim swapRow = rnd.Next(0, row + 1)

        ' Swap all columns of the row
        For column = arr.GetLowerBound(0) To arr.GetUpperBound(0)
            Dim temp = arr(column, row)
            arr(column, row) = arr(column, swapRow)
            arr(column, swapRow) = temp
        Next column
    Next row
End Sub
```

Obviously, you can swap `Get...Bound(0)` and `Get...Bound(1)` to shuffle along the other axis of the 2D array.

Comment: Thank you for reading the question: "And WITHOUT changing the original "Questions" array type". I already knew that if the original array was say a Object\Class List then life would have much easier. However for various reasons I have to maintain the original 2D array Questions. Great reply BTW, and thanks.