# Randomize answers in RadioButtons through Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I'm currently working on my multiple-choice quiz and am having trouble with this section. I'm trying to get the answers from the database and have them randomly go into the radio buttons. So far I have each of them go into radio buttons but since I'm new to this, I'm unsure of how to randomize it.

```
Private Sub Answers()
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb"
    cn.Open()

    cm.CommandText = ("SELECT pAns1,pAns2,pAns3,CorrectAns FROM MCQ WHERE QuestionNumber = '" & n & "'")
    cm.Connection = cn
    dr = cm.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()
    RadioButton1.Text = dr.Item("pAns1")
    RadioButton2.Text = dr.Item("pAns2")
    RadioButton3.Text = dr.Item("pAns3")
    RadioButton4.Text = dr.Item("CorrectAns")
End Sub
```

Comment: Still have the sql injection issue, I see. This is **IMPORTANT!**

Comment: It's a project for school, does it really matter?

Comment: There are two kinds of security issues that are too important to **ever** handle the wrong way... even for learning projects in school. One of those is password handling. _Never_ store passwords in plain-text, not even when building assignments for school. (Even encryption isn't good enough.) The other is sql injection. An instructor should show you parameterized queries _before_ asking you to build something like this.

Comment: To be honest mate, we haven't been taught anything in lessons, I'm just teaching myself. How would I go about trying to fix it?

Comment: Look at the `OleDbParameter` type and `OleDbCommand.Parameters` property.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Relax, please. You don't even know the origin of variable `n`. The use of parameters is, of course, first choice, but most often for other reasons than SQL injection, indeed when touching _Access SQL_ which doesn't allow nested SQL statements.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: @Mary, yeh the combobox is dropdown only the user cannot enter anything into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like:

```vb
'A class level variable.
Private ReadOnly rand As New Random

Private Sub Answers()
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=login.accdb")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT pAns1, pAns2, pAns3, CorrectAns FROM MCQ WHERE QuestionNumber = ?", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionNumber", n)
            cn.Open()
            Using r As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim arr = {
                        r.GetOrdinal("pAns1"),
                        r.GetOrdinal("pAns2"),
                        r.GetOrdinal("pAns3")
                    }.OrderBy(Function(x) rand.Next).ToArray
                If r.Read Then
                    RadioButton1.Text = r.Item(arr(0)).ToString
                    RadioButton2.Text = r.Item(arr(1)).ToString
                    RadioButton3.Text = r.Item(arr(2)).ToString
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Please note:

- The snippet respects the mentioned above comments.
- You should close the connection and dispose the disposable objects. The `Using ... End Using` block will do that for you.
- For the *randomize* requirement, we get the columns ordinals to create an array of integers and *shuffle* the contents. You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358857/shuffling-an-array-of-strings-in-vb-net) post for different arrays *shuffling* ways.

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Agree. Whether or not I already know that, A reminder is always good and appreciated. Thank you mate.