# How do I generate random numbers from a list of specific numbers that I have?

Tags: vb.net

I want my application to populate random sets of numbers using a list of specific numbers that i chose.  For example; I have a set of numbers (1,3,5,9,21,70,56).  I want to be able to randomize the order in which these numbers are selected.  Is that possible?

Comment: [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a list of 1000 numbers using only those you gave:

```
Dim r as New Random()
Dim thousand as New List(Of Integer)(1000)

'short way to create an array
Dim onlyFrom = {1,3,5,9,21,70,56}

For i = 1 to 1000 
  thousand.Add(onlyFrom(r.Next(0, onlyFrom.Length)))
Next i
```

It repeatedly asks a Random for a random integer between 0 and the array length. Next() may return the lower number, but never the upper number. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

If you want to shuffle those numbers you gave into a random order, easy way to use LINQ:

```
Dim r as New Random()
Dim onlyFrom = {1,3,5,9,21,70,56}

Dim shuffled = onlyFrom.OrderBy(Function(x) r.Next()).ToArray()
```

Note: **Do not use New Random() in a loop**

Answer (score 1):

```
Randomize()
Dim NumberList= {1,3,5,9,21,70,56}
' Generate random value between 1 and 7,  or use NumberList length to make it generic
Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int(( 7 * Rnd()) + 1))  
return NumberList(value-1)
```

*** The above code may produce the same value multiple times in a series. so if the requirement is that a different value be produced from the array each time when the code is called seven times, this wouldn't work ***

If the requirement is to have a different value from the array each time for the first 7 calls,  you may use Shuffle function as laid out here [Shuffling an array of strings in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358857/shuffling-an-array-of-strings-in-vb-net)